# VS code formatter using the same configuration as the linter

Tags: python, formatting

In VS code, when you save a python file (using cmd+s), it runs a formatter over the python file. The configuration of this VS Code formatter is different than the one used in the NURO linter. Then when you push to a branch, the pre-push hook returns an error and prevents you from pushing. As a result, we need to run the Nuro linter manually.

Is there a way to set up the VS code python formatter to use the same configuration as the linter?

I looked into the directory `tools/lint` and I couldn't find anything useful.

Comment: please clarify what you mean exactly...  it is not clear.

Comment: how to ask a good question:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I updated the message. I hope it's more precise.